# Where to find the source of com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.JDBCRealm?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I am looking for the source code of:

**com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.JDBCRealm** => **version 3.1.2.2**

I only find the source at version 3.1.1, I really can't find version 3.1.2.2. Could anybody help me ?

Thank you in avance & kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Check the below link,.

http://grepcode.com/file/maven.java.net/content/groups/promoted/org.glassfish.main.security/security/3.1.2-b18/com/sun/enterprise/security/auth/realm/jdbc/JDBCRealm.java#JDBCRealm

Comment: thanks for your fast answer. do you think 3.1.2-b18 is equivalent to 3.1.2.2 ? As I see, the "digestrealm-password-enc-algorithm" property is included (which was new somewhen after version 3.1.x).

Comment: I hope both are equal. Since 3.1.2.2 is a maintenance version. They fixed few issues 

    NetBeans bug 211962

    JAX-WS issue JAX_WS-1059

    GlassFish Server issue GLASSFISH-18446                                          For information visit http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24939/release-notes.htm